# Protractor+AngularJS+Jasmine - test press and hold item

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, ionic-framework

Very new with AngularJS and Protractor, but I think I am going to the right direction so far.

My site has a list of items when you click and hold the item for X seconds, it opens a modal window.

How can I simulate that behavior in Protractor/Jasmine?

I know there is the "click()" event, but I want the "click and hold" event

I am sure there is someone that knows how to simulate that.

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use [`mouseDown()`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/actionsequence.js#164) first:

```
/**
 * Presses a mouse button. The mouse button will not be released until
 * {@link #mouseUp} is called, regardless of whether that call is made in this
 * sequence or another. The behavior for out-of-order events (e.g. mouseDown,
 * click) is undefined.
 ...
 */
```

Then, call `browser.sleep()` for X seconds.

Then, call [`mouseUp()`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/actionsequence.js#193) to release the mouse click:

```
/**
 * Releases a mouse button. Behavior is undefined for calling this function
 * without a previous call to {@link #mouseDown}.
 ...
 */
```

Code:

```
browser.actions().mouseDown(element).perform();
browser.sleep(5000);
browser.actions().mouseUp(element).perform();
```

where `element` is a target element for `click-and-hold`.

---

Working example (based on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LysCF/13/embedded/result/)):

```
require('jasmine-expect');

describe('Test Click And Hold', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('http://jsfiddle.net/LysCF/13/embedded/result/');
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    it('should show appropriate list elements after click and hold', function () {
        var frame = browser.findElement(by.xpath('//div[@id="result"]/iframe'));
        browser.switchTo().frame(frame);

        var element = browser.findElement(by.css('div.hold_trigger'));
        browser.actions().mouseDown(element).perform();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();

        // check expectations
    });
});
```

Comment: WOW! Now I know that I don't know much! ;-) I thought I had to use only protractor command, but it seems that I need to know and learn Jasmine much more! Big Thanks!

Comment: The easiest explanation I have ever seen.