# Custom browser actions in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**The problem:**

In one of our tests we have a ["long click"/"click and hold" functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300433/protractorangularjsjasmine-test-press-and-hold-item) that we solve by using:

```
browser.actions().mouseDown(element).perform();
browser.sleep(5000);
browser.actions().mouseUp(element).perform();
```

Which we would like to ideally solve in one line by having `sleep()` a part of the action chain:

```
browser.actions().mouseDown(element).sleep(5000).mouseUp(element).perform();
```

Clearly, this would not work since there is [no "sleep" action](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions).

Another practical example could be the "human-like typing". For instance:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click()
   .sendKeys("t").sleep(50)  // we should randomize the delays, strictly speaking
   .sendKeys("e").sleep(10)
   .sendKeys("s").sleep(20)
   .sendKeys("t")
   .perform();
```

<sup>Note that these are just examples, the question is meant to be generic.</sup>

**The Question:**

Is it possible to extend `browser.actions()` action sequences and introduce custom actions?

---

Comment: Digging into Selenium sources as far as I understand it would not be possible to actually extend actions, I would consider creating some kind of a wrapper like @John Stennett has suggested. If you are interested, I could give an explanation of why it could not be done (from my point of view, maybe it is possible).

Comment: @MichaelRadionov yeah, I was afraid wrapping it is the only option (there is nothing wrong with it though). I would appreciate your insight, your answers are always detailed and helpful. Besides, I hope the topic would help not only me to solve my current problem but also others with similar requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, you can extend the actions framework.** But, strictly speaking, getting something like:

```
browser.actions().mouseDown(element).sleep(5000).mouseUp(element).perform();
```

means messing with Selenium's guts. So, YMMV.

Note that the [Protractor documentation](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) refers to `webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions` when explaining actions, which I take to mean that it does not modify or add to what Selenium provides.

The class of object returned by `webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions` is `webdriver.ActionSequence`. The method that actually causes the sequence to do anything is `webdriver.ActionSequence.prototype.perform`. In the default implementation, this function takes the commands that were recorded when you called `.sendKeys()` or `.mouseDown()` and has the driver to which the `ActionSequence` is associated schedule them in order. So adding a `.sleep` method **CANNOT be done this way**:

```
webdriver.ActionSequence.prototype.sleep = function (delay) {
    var driver = this.driver_;
    driver.sleep(delay);
    return this;
};
```

Otherwise, the sleep would happen **out of order**. What you have to do is *record* the effect you want so that it is executed later.

Now, the other thing to consider is that the default `.perform()` only expects to execute `webdriver.Command`, which are commands to be sent to the browser. Sleeping is not one such command. So `.perform()` has to be modified to handle what we are going to record with `.sleep()`. In the code below I've opted to have `.sleep()` record a function and modified `.perform()` to handle functions in addition to `webdriver.Command`.

Here is what the whole thing looks like, once put together. I've first given an example using stock Selenium and then added the patches and an example using the modified code.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

// Do it using what Selenium inherently provides.

var browser = new chrome.Driver();

browser.get("http://www.google.com");

browser.findElement(By.name("q")).click();
browser.actions().sendKeys("foo").perform();
browser.sleep(2000);
browser.actions().sendKeys("bar").perform();
browser.sleep(2000);

// Do it with an extended ActionSequence.

webdriver.ActionSequence.prototype.sleep = function (delay) {
    var driver = this.driver_;
    // This just records the action in an array. this.schedule_ is part of
    // the "stock" code.
    this.schedule_("sleep", function () { driver.sleep(delay); });
    return this;
};

webdriver.ActionSequence.prototype.perform = function () {
    var actions = this.actions_.slice();
    var driver = this.driver_;
    return driver.controlFlow().execute(function() {
        actions.forEach(function(action) {
            var command = action.command;
            // This is a new test to distinguish functions, which 
            // require handling one way and the usual commands which
            // require a different handling.
            if (typeof command === "function")
                // This puts the command in its proper place within
                // the control flow that was created above
                // (driver.controlFlow()).
                driver.flow_.execute(command);
            else
                driver.schedule(command, action.description);
        });
    }, 'ActionSequence.perform');
};

browser.get("http://www.google.com");

browser.findElement(By.name("q")).click();
browser.actions().sendKeys("foo")
    .sleep(2000)
    .sendKeys("bar")
    .sleep(2000)
    .perform();
browser.quit();
```

In my implementation of `.perform()` I've replaced the `goog...` functions that Selenium's code uses with stock JavaScript.

Comment: Nice find! I've gone deeper trying to add a custom command, but it's not that easy, because executor uses only registered commands and API for adding a new command is being hidden by `selenium-webdriver'. I guess knowing how control flow works is essential in this kind of things.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did (based on the perfect @Louis's answer).

Put the following into `onPrepare()` in the protractor config:

```
// extending action sequences
protractor.ActionSequence.prototype.sleep = function (delay) {
    var driver = this.driver_;
    this.schedule_("sleep", function () { driver.sleep(delay); });
    return this;
};

protractor.ActionSequence.prototype.perform = function () {
    var actions = this.actions_.slice();
    var driver = this.driver_;
    return driver.controlFlow().execute(function() {
        actions.forEach(function(action) {
            var command = action.command;
            if (typeof command === "function")
                driver.flow_.execute(command);
            else
                driver.schedule(command, action.description);
        });
    }, 'ActionSequence.perform');
};

protractor.ActionSequence.prototype.clickAndHold = function (elm) {
    return this.mouseDown(elm).sleep(3000).mouseUp(elm);
};
```

Now you'll have `sleep()` and `clickAndHold()` browser actions available. Example usage:

```
browser.actions().clickAndHold(element).perform();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is possible to extend the `browser.actions()` function but that is currently above my skill level so I'll lay out the route that I would take to solve this issue. I would recommend setting up a "*HelperFunctions.js*" Page Object that will contain all of these Global Helper Functions. In that file you can list your `browser` functions and reference it in multiple tests with all of the code in one location.

This is the code for the "HelperFunctions.js" file that I would recommend setting up:

```
var HelperFunctions = function() {
    this.longClick = function(targetElement) {
        browser.actions().mouseDown(targetElement).perform();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        browser.actions().mouseUp(targetElement).perform();
    };
};

module.exports = new HelperFunctions();
```

---

Then in your Test you can reference the Helper file like this:

```
var HelperFunctions = require('../File_Path_To/HelperFunctions.js');

describe('Example Test', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.helperFunctions = HelperFunctions;

        browser.get('http://www.example.com/');
    });

    it('Should test something.', function() {
        var Element = element(by.className('targetedClassName'));
        this.helperFunctions.longClick(Element);
    });
});
```

---

In my Test Suite I have a few Helper files setup and they are referenced through out all of my Tests.

Answer (score 2):

I have very little knowledge of selenium or protractor, but I'll give it a shot.

This assumes that

```
browser.actions().mouseDown(element).mouseUp(element).perform();
```

is valid syntax for your issue, if so then this would likely do the trick

```
browser.action().sleep = function(){
    browser.sleep.apply(this, arguments);
    return browser.action()
}
```