# How to click the same button more than 50 times in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

How to click the same button more than 50 times by using loop statement in protractor? Will protractor support this action?

Here's my locator :

```
var nudge= element(by.xpath("//a[@class='isd-flat-icons fi-down']"));
nudge.click();
```

Comment: offcourse you can use a loop to execute click 50 times

Comment: On a side note, why would you click a button 50 times in a row? Is it a functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try simple for loop in javascript:

```
var nudge= element(by.xpath("//a[@class='isd-flat-icons fi-down']"));

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 
    nudge.click();
}
```

The above script will click the button exactly 50 times. Before implementing this script consider:

- The above script will click the button as fast as possible
- Some sites can become unresponsive after even such small load

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this through the [browser actions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) (should be better performance-wise, since actions are sent in a single command when you "perform" them):

```
var nudge = $("a.isd-flat-icons.fi-down");

var actions = browser.actions();
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 
    actions = actions.click(nudge);
}
actions.perform();
```

Note that, if you want to introduce a delay between every click action, you can do that by having a [custom "sleep" browser action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872738/771848):

```
var nudge = $("a.isd-flat-icons.fi-down");

var actions = browser.actions();
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 
    actions = actions.click(nudge).sleep(500);
}
actions.perform();
```

The `$` here is a shortcut for the "by.css" locator, which would be, generally speaking and according to the [Style Guide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide), a better choice when using an XPath location technique.