# How to press BACKSPACE or ENTER multiple times in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I understand that we can initiate keypress events like Backspace or ENTER in protractor with the help of `protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE or ENTER`. But , how do i do this action multiple times? Is it just adding another line of it or any good approach towards it?

Comment: Please check this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393237/how-to-click-the-same-button-more-than-50-times-in-protractor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click the same button more than 50 times in protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393237/how-to-click-the-same-button-more-than-50-times-in-protractor)

Answer (score 1):

We have written a common functions to do the same.

```
exports.commonfunc = {
      pressKey: function(key) {
        switch (key) {
          case 'Enter':
            browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
            break;
          case 'Backspace':
            browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE).perform();
            break;
        }
      },
      pressKeyNtimes: function(key, n) {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          this.pressKey(key);
        }
      }
}
```

Now we using commonfunc in another class as below :

```
exports.Login = {
 commonfunc: Object.create(require('../common/commonfunctions.js').commonfunc),

 iClickEnterTwice: function(){
  this.commonfunc.pressKeyNtimes('Enter',2);
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!