# How do i extract extract all 'a' tags with attribute 'title' from li

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

How do I extract all a tags Title value. Following is the xml structure. The `ulTopMenu` is a hover dropdown. I am using protractor.

```
<ul id="ulTopMenu">
<li>
<li>
<li>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
            <a href="" title = "test2"></a></li>
        <li>
            <a href ="" title = "test1" ></a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Following is what i tried

```
var menus = element.all(by.css('#ulTopMenu > li'));
    var submenu = element.all(by.css('#ulTopMenu > li .submenu li')).all(by.tagName('a'));
    browser.actions().mouseMove(menus.get(3)).perform().then(function () {
        submenu.filter(function (elem, index) {
            return elem.getAttribute('title').then(function (val) {
                return val === 'test1'
            })
        }).first().click();
```

It always return me an error saying Element not visible

Comment: You need to extract the text or click on these links? Also you would need to chain your mouseMove to the submenu and then to link and the click. All in one go. Not like this

Comment: Can you consider a Answer/Solution based on Selenium(Java)?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes sure will do

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to debug without actually executing the code and seeing what is happening, but here is an educated guess - should not you first open up the dropdown itself:

```
var dropdown = element(by.id("ulTopMenu"));
var submenu = dropdown.$("ul.submenu");
var desiredMenuItem = submenu.$('li > a[title=test1]');

browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(dropdown)
    .mouseMove(submenu)
    .click(desiredMenuItem)
    .perform()
```

Note how I'm locating the link by the title with a CSS selector.

And, note the assumptions I made when applying the actions - see if you need to change the way dropdowns open - via mouse move or click.

You may also need to add delays between the actions - we've been using a [custom `sleep()` browser action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872738/771848) in similar cases.

---

If you just need to extract the link texts with attribute `title`:

```
$$("#ulTopMenu ul.subMenu li > a[title]").getText().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is absolutely correct. If it is a drop-down so how usually submenu appears? Yes, you should firstly click on it (drop-down). Only after it submenu will be visible and you will be able to click on submenu item.

Comment: The submenu appears when you mouseover the dropdown